# ios http-request with provider proxy - site is always online

Tags: ios, objective-c, httprequest

I got a piece of code, that returns the header information from a website. If I shut down the service on port 80 and the website is offline, the app still returns the header information to me. This is due to the proxy of some providers.
The first three times it works correctly. It responds to online or offine. After the requests, the website is constantly online for the app.

This is my code:

```
- (IBAction)fastCheckButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"TextfieldURL ist: %@", _textFieldUrl);
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSString* userAgent = @"Desktop";
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSInteger statusCode = [response statusCode];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:_textFieldUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0];
    [request addValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];

    //NSData *conn = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSData* conn = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                         returningResponse:&response
                                                     error:&error];

    [self connection:conn didReceiveResponse:response];


}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    NSInteger statusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];
    NSDictionary* headers = [httpResponse allHeaderFields];

    NSLog(@"\n \n DELEGATE STATUS -->: \n \n %d \n  \n HEADERS -->: \n \n \n %@", statusCode, headers);
}
```

And this is a sample output with my apache running on port 80. Done over Wi-Fi

```
DELEGATE STATUS -->: 

 200 

 HEADERS -->: 




{
    "Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 38;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Wed, 29 May 2013 13:42:34 GMT";
    Etag = "\"b1fcde-26-4dc47bfd46880\"";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=80";
    "Last-Modified" = "Thu, 09 May 2013 11:57:06 GMT";
    Server = "Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1"; }
```

If i did that over 3g with T-Mobile I also gat a "Age = X" field in the header.
The problem is now, even if i shut down the service on port 80, that app still says that it's online and the age still counts foreward.

Over Wifi everything works perfectly. When the site is down I got the right status code and the error message. If the site doen't exist I got a 0.

I only have these problems over mobile network.

How can I pass the proxy to get the correct status from the site?

Comment: Probably your mobile network provider does some caching of this site. I do not see an expired or max-age tag in the response.

Comment: The "Age=X" entry, only appears, if I do this over mobile network. But how can I pass the proxy???

Comment: Did you try to add a parameter to the URL, which is not evaluated by the server, something like "?nonsense=…" with a UUID?